# How to train from scratch on CPU in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train MNIST on mobileNet. So started with the installation of the models git repo. After I have gotten the dataset on board, and I also followed the previous steps of installation. Later also converted the MNIST to the TFRecord format. Then when I ran the train_image_classifier.py form the slim folder of the models repo, I get the following logs. (NOTE: I am using anaconda python aliased as **boa**, and have stock python alongside.)

`boa train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} --dataset_name=mnist --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} --model_name=mobilenet_v1`

> WARNING:tensorflow:From train_image_classifier.py:468: softmax_cross_entropy (from tensorflow.contrib.losses.python.losses.loss_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-30.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy instead. Note that the order of the logits and labels arguments has been changed.
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/losses/loss_ops.py:398: compute_weighted_loss (from tensorflow.contrib.losses.python.losses.loss_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-30.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use tf.losses.compute_weighted_loss instead.
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/losses/python/losses/loss_ops.py:151: add_loss (from tensorflow.contrib.losses.python.losses.loss_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-30.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use tf.losses.add_loss instead.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
>   2017-09-14 11:23:12.377137: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-09-14 11:23:12.377158: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-09-14 11:23:12.377162: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-09-14 11:23:12.377165: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-09-14 11:23:12.377169: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>   2017-09-14 11:23:14.890614: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:669] Ignoring device specification /device:GPU:0 for node 'fifo_queue_Dequeue' because the input edge from 'prefetch_queue/fifo_queue' is a reference connection and already has a device field set to /device:CPU:0
>   INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , Cannot assign a device to node 'gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
>      [[Node: gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape, gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
>
> Caused by op u'gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs', defined at:
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 574, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 534, in main
>       var_list=variables_to_train)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 297, in optimize_clones
>       optimizer, clone, num_clones, regularization_losses, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 261, in _optimize_clone
>       clone_grad = optimizer.compute_gradients(sum_loss, **kwargs)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients
>       colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 560, in gradients
>       grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 368, in _MaybeCompile
>       return grad_fn()  # Exit early
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 560, in 
>       grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py", line 609, in _SubGrad
>       rx, ry = gen_array_ops._broadcast_gradient_args(sx, sy)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 411, in _broadcast_gradient_args
>       name=name)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack()
>
> ...which was originally created as op u'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub', defined at:
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 574, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>   [elided 0 identical lines from previous traceback]
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 474, in main
>       clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, clone_fn, [batch_queue])
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
>       outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 457, in clone_fn
>       logits, end_points = network_fn(images)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/nets/nets_factory.py", line 114, in network_fn
>       return func(images, num_classes, is_training=is_training)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py", line 323, in mobilenet_v1
>       conv_defs=conv_defs)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py", line 232, in mobilenet_v1_base
>       scope=end_point)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 927, in convolution
>       outputs = normalizer_fn(outputs, **normalizer_params)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 528, in batch_norm
>       outputs = layer.apply(inputs, training=is_training)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 320, in apply
>       return self.**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 290, in **call**
>       outputs = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
>      [[Node: gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape, gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 574, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 570, in main
>       sync_optimizer=optimizer if FLAGS.sync_replicas else None)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 725, in train
>       master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess:
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in **enter**
>       return self.gen.next()
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 960, in managed_session
>       self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 788, in stop
>       stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
>       six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 949, in managed_session
>       start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 706, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
>       init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 262, in prepare_session
>       sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
>       feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
>       target_list, options, run_metadata)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
>      [[Node: gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape, gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
>
> Caused by op u'gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs', defined at:
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 574, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 534, in main
>       var_list=variables_to_train)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 297, in optimize_clones
>       optimizer, clone, num_clones, regularization_losses, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 261, in _optimize_clone
>       clone_grad = optimizer.compute_gradients(sum_loss, **kwargs)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients
>       colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 560, in gradients
>       grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 368, in _MaybeCompile
>       return grad_fn()  # Exit early
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 560, in 
>       grad_scope, op, func_call, lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py", line 609, in _SubGrad
>       rx, ry = gen_array_ops._broadcast_gradient_args(sx, sy)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 411, in _broadcast_gradient_args
>       name=name)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack()
>
> ...which was originally created as op u'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub', defined at:
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 574, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>   [elided 0 identical lines from previous traceback]
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 474, in main
>       clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, clone_fn, [batch_queue])
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
>       outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "train_image_classifier.py", line 457, in clone_fn
>       logits, end_points = network_fn(images)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/nets/nets_factory.py", line 114, in network_fn
>       return func(images, num_classes, is_training=is_training)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py", line 323, in mobilenet_v1
>       conv_defs=conv_defs)
>     File "/home/csb/path/to/projects/RnD/mobilenet/tensorflow_models/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py", line 232, in mobilenet_v1_base
>       scope=end_point)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 927, in convolution
>       outputs = normalizer_fn(outputs, **normalizer_params)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 528, in batch_norm
>       outputs = layer.apply(inputs, training=is_training)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 320, in apply
>       return self.**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
>     File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 290, in **call**
>       outputs = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
>      [[Node: gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape, gradients/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Sub_grad/Shape_1)]]

Later I found out that I am getting the error message because there is no GPU on the system. Can we not train on TF without GPU? If we can train on CPU, please tell the changes to be made in the code.

Comment: The code that you're running explicitly assigns some variables on the GPU. In the code, look for all occurences of `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` and replace `gpu:0` with `cpu:0`

Comment: There is no occurences of `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` in the train_image_classifier code. Should I check for it somewhere else? Or is there any FLAGS I can assign explicitly on command line?

Comment: Where did you get the code from, do you have a link to a GitHub repo?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim

Comment: The device is set in /deployment/model_deploy.py in optimizer_device(), inputs_device() and variables_device() - check which value each of these return

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, was on another project. How do I check the value returned ?

Comment: You could just print it to the console, for example. You can also try to override all three methods and return "/cpu:0" in all of them

Comment: I could get rid of the error by adding `--clone_on_cpu=True` flag. I thought the program was set up to know what resources are available. But I guess it wanted GPU to create clones (which I don't know what it is).

Comment: Now I am getting a different issue when I train MNIST Data with mobileNet. `python train_image_classifier.py     --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR}     --dataset_name=mnist     --dataset_split_name=train     --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR}     --model_name=mobilenet_v1 --clone_on_cpu=True`, when I run this I get 
>tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: input must have 3 channels but input only has 1 channels.
  [[Node: distort_image/distort_color_2/adjust_saturation/RGBToHSV = RGBToHSV[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](distort_image/Switch_3:1)]]

Comment: @aseipel, Can we not train MNIST dataset using MobileNet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model_deploy.py in `deployment/` folder uses GPU for creating clones on it. We need specify specifically to clone on CPU using the Flag `--clone_on_cpu=True`. So the the command becomes
`python train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} --dataset_name=mnist --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} --model_name=mobilenet_v1 --clone_on_cpu=True`. Got rid of `boa` alias name. But we cannot train MNIST using mobileNet, so the actual correct command will be
`python train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} --dataset_name=mnist --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} --model_name=lenet --clone_on_cpu=True`.

Comment: The {TRAIN_DIR} and {DATASET_DIR} has to be set prehand.